# How i can send array strings to telegram?

Tags: java, telegram

I'm sending a message to telegram channel and i have error

Simple string sent, but modified by the type of part of the array is not sent

```
 String urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage?chat_id=%s&text=%s";

    String apiToken = "123843242734723";
    String chatId = "@Example";
    String text = Array[i]+ " hello";

    urlString = String.format(urlString, apiToken, chatId, text);

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character in URL

Comment: have you tried urlencoding the apiToken and chatId and text? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

Comment: What is array ` Array[i]`?

Comment: @ieggel String array, used for example

Comment: @gandalf, please show us the value of Array[i]. I suspect the error lies there.

Comment: @ieggel String[] Array= time.split("\\d\n");First String
String1
String2
44:2 something like this in array[i]

Comment: @gandalf, please show more code. also the time var.

Comment: @ieggel  Elements elemenx = doc.select("div.elements, span.team");
String time = elemenx.html();
String[] Array = time.split("\\d\n");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: `String apiToken = "123843242734723";` these should be hidden from above code for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the content in Array[i] comes from a html input element. I suspect there is some kind of whitespace such as `\r\n` that is passed to the URL, which then causes the `MalformedURLException`.

Here my approach:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Here is where you would assign the content of your HTML element
        // I just put a string there that might resemble what you get from your HTML
        String timeHtmlInput = "12:00\r\n13:00\r\n14:00\r\n";

        // Split by carriage return
        String timeTokens[] = timeHtmlInput.split("\r\n");

        String urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage?chat_id=%s&text=%s";
        String apiToken = "123843242734723";
        String chatId = "@Example";
        String time = timeTokens[0];
        String text = time + "Hello";

        urlString = String.format(urlString, 
                URLEncoder.encode(apiToken, "UTF-8"), 
                URLEncoder.encode(chatId, "UTF-8"),
                URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"));

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        System.out.println(url);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    }
```

BTW it is always good practice to encode the query string parameters, such as:

```java
URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"));
```

as they also might contain some other illegal characters.
Hope this helps!

Comment: It Works!!! Thanks for help. I would not find the solution by myself. Have a nice day, you are a very kind person

Comment: @Ross you're welcome :). Keep on coding, you will improve faster than you think.

Answer (score 0):

The @ character must be encoded. E.g. replace it directly with %40.
but you can also use

```
URLEncoder.encode(s,"UTF-8")
```

Comment: that is not the reason he is getting `java.net.MalformedURLException`.

Comment: the `encode` method should be used because there might me more invalid characters in the whole url.

Comment: Encoding the whole URL String will not work. Only the query strings should be encoded. Otherwise the proocol it will result in `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol`.

Comment: @ieggel this is a good additional advice. My answer was more of a general hint how to encode a generic string.